# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration, facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

Hi guys i am getting this error:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

many people are facing this error because their redirect url mismatch or either they are placing wrong clint id or secret id, but 
in my case 
1. Redirect URL is fine,
2. app id and app secret are also fine.

what could be the problem? please help me

Comment: What should I add into the **site URL**, if I don't have the public domain name yet, but I have the ip address of my VM that running my site. Can anyone please advise ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set your domain within your application in the application settings.

See the following screenshot, the "App Domains" setting is set to "testapp.com".
Your URL for your Page Tab for example has to be of the same domain as the on you specified here.

[image]

Comment: what will be the value for App Domains for localhost:1212

Comment: Facebook applications don't work well with localhost, you should look into making a virtual host for your project so you have an actual URL to put there.

Comment: btw thanx a lot buddy, i just put localhost there and it worked. thank you :)
it is not accepting it with localhost:someport

Comment: @SanjayBathre Ah nice, localhost used to be a pain to work with Facebook. If you could accept my answer, that'd be great.

Comment: What should I add into the **site URL**, if I don't have the public domain name yet, but I have the ip address of my VM that running my site. Can anyone please advise ?

Comment: @ihue it will not work without a domain name, just an IP address will not suffice. If it's only for local development, you could set a domain name in your Hosts file, on Windows that is probably located on "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" and on UNIX based systems it will most likely be located in "/etc/hosts"