# Ionic Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2

I integrated facebook in my ionic app but keeps getting the error

Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the app settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.

I added the platform and saved it. What am I doing wrong over here ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting in the console is because your app isn't configured properly in the Facebook Developers page.

Check your `config.xml`

```
<widget id="com.ionicframework.coaching154009" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

We need the widget id. Then go to facebook (developer mode obviously), check your app.

Configuration->Basic->Add platform->Android.
Google play app name-> .

In this case: `com.ionicframework.coaching154009`

Google play app name: `com.ionicframework.coaching154009`

Then accept and save changes.

[Cross reference #404](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/404)

Refer these links as well -

- [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16347026/4694013)
- [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036317/4694013)
- [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7184911/4694013)

Comment: I have followed this procedure but still gets the same error